# I there a way to vertically align text in slickgrid header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slickgrid

I have wrapped some header into two line using this.

```
.slick-column-name { white-space: normal; }

.slick-header-column.ui-state-default{ height:30px; vertical-align:middle;}
```

But the single line headers stays on top of the cell. Is there any way to vertically align these "single line" headers into center?

Comment: Colud you provide a link with a demo?

Comment: Hey can you please show us some html as well ?? so maybe I can better understand the question ! I am sure there is a simple way to solve this ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mind like this:

```
.slick-column-name { white-space: normal; display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height: 100px; background: red;  }

.slick-header-column.ui-state-default{ height:30px; line-height:30px; }
```

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xJUMv/

Answer (score -1):

This will enforce the vertical align middle

```
.slick-cell:after {
    height: 100%; content: ""; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; width: 0;
}
```